# Require derived class to provide member function template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a base class and a bunch of derived classes. I want to specify that the derived classes need to supply a specific member function template. With regular functions, I would specify a pure virtual function

```
class A
{
    virtual void f() = 0;
}
```

which I would then override in my derived classes. However, as templates can't be virtual, I don't know how I would do it in this case.

```
class A
{
    template <class T>
    virtual void f() = 0; // this is not allowed
}
```

Is there a different way of requiring child classes to specify a member function template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply document that derived classes must have that template. The requirement will be enforced, since code that tries to call the function will fail to compile if it's missing.

You could make the code slightly more self-documenting, and perhaps get better diagnostics, by deleting the function in the base class:

```
// Derived classes must provide this template
template <class T> void f() = delete;
```

One day, concepts might provide a nicer way of specifying a non-virtual interface; but we don't have them yet.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Does the fact that this is not available yet somehow imply that I might have made some shoddy design decisions?